# Make use of a color scale in a random map

Tags: color

In my class I often need to work with color map images. I would show the image and try to make inferences/observations about different subjects. Often times I need to actually quantify some aspects, but it is always very approximate and somehow vague because the images are provided "as is" and I do not necessarily know their content a priori.

Let's imagine I'm working with two images (*). I would love to tell my computer to "learn" the color scale bar so I can click at any point in the map to get the value of altitude at that point? Image 1 is a discrete color scale bar, while Image 2 has a continuous color mapping. I included both examples because maybe there are differences in the approach of how to do this.

So, is there a software/way to do this? Preferably open source. I tried ImageJ and couldn't come up with a decent solution.

(*) Image 1: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/AYool_topography_15min.png

(*) Image 2: http://topocreator.com/ned-jpg/city_a/600/co.jpg

(*) I do not own any of these images, just examples I found online to illustrate my point.

Comment: I am afraid that this question is off-topic for DSP.SE. The [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).SE might have something more to say on the subject though. Having said that, if this were a height map on some platform like MATLAB for example, I would bring both height maps to the same scale (by linearly mapping one to the extents of the other) and then plot them on the same colormap. In this way, the correspondence of colours would match exactly.

Comment: Isn't this an image processing question?

Comment: So the colorbars are part of the image file already?

Comment: DSP.SE: "Q&A for practitioners of the art and science of signal, image and video processing". Thus I thought it was appropriate to ask here, but sorry if it's not.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the links, the color bars are part of the image file. I usually get the images from colleagues or just from internet.